# chome.tabs.executeScript from external file? What permissions do I need to change in manifest.json?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'd like to run chrome.tabs.executeScript to run a file stored on a remote server (for testing purposes, that server is localhost).  Here is the code I have so far:

```js
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: 'http://localhost/js/myTestFile.js'}, function() {
    //Do some stuff on completion
});
```

I know that by default, programmatically injected content scripts cannot be sourced from a remote location, but that you can "whitelist" certain sources in the manifest to change that.  Here is my manifest at the moment:

```js
  //Extensions Permissions
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "notifications",
  ],

  //External access permissions
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": [
      "http://localhost/*",
    ]
  }

  //Directories available to the extension
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "js/*",
    "html/*",
    "img/*"
  ],

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["js/lib/require-2.1.8.min.js", "js/extension/contentManager.js"],
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
```

In what way can I modify the manifest to allow a remote JS file to be injected as a content script?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask for "tabs" permissions to inject script into a page. Note that you can inject code or a link to the script. There may be an issue injecting a remote script, but you can pull down the JS and inject that directly into the page.

To include a remote script into the background page, you need to list the domain in content_security_policy and it must be https unless it is on localhost.